# How to handle 404 in cowboy_static when file not found

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have very important query regarding cowboy_static

```
{"/api/assets/[...]",cowboy_static, {dir,"/home/upload_dir/"}},
```

{"/api/assets/[...]",cowboy_static, {dir,"/home/upload_dir/"}},

Everything is working fine but I failed to send a default image (for example not_available.jpg)  for 404 . 
Is it possible in cowboy_static to send a default image if request image/URL not found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a way of doing it with just `cowboy_static` handler. The documentation ([static files](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.6/guide/static_files/)) says

> Cowboy comes with a ready to use handler for serving static files. It
>   is provided as a convenience for serving files during development.
>
> For systems in production, consider using one of the many Content Distribution Network > (CDN) available on the market, as they are the best solution for serving files.

so some functionality may be missing there. If you really want to serve 404 custom page from Cowboy, I think the only option is a custom handler instead of `cowboy_static`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.